# Why is read hanging my bash script?

Tags: git, bash, unix, git-post-receive, post-receive-email

I had a similar problem to this with Python using `readlines()` but I'm not sure if it's the same here.

The `read` command is hanging my bash script.

```
generate_email()
{
    # --- Arguments
    oldrev=$(git rev-parse $1)
    newrev=$(git rev-parse $2)
    refname="$3"

    # ... some code ...
}

# ... more code ...

while read oldrev newrev refname
do
    generate_email $oldrev $newrev $refname
done
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Seems like you're expecting input (with 3 delimited arguments) to be parsed. You need to pipe it in. Either pass in that input to the script you've included above, or explicitly to the while loop (`[some-command] | while read oldrev newrev refname...`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not telling read to read from anything.  So it's just waiting for input from `stdin`.

If you're wanting to read from a file, you need to use `read` like so:

```
while read -r oldrev newrev refname; do
  generate_email "$oldrev" "$newrev" "$refname"
done < /path/to/file
```

Note the `< /path/to/file`.  That's where you're actually telling read to read from the file.

If you're wanting to read from an input stream, you can use `while read` like so:

```
grep 'stuffInFile' /path/to/file |
while read -r oldrev newrev refname; do
  generate_email "$oldrev" "$newrev" "$refname"
done
```

Comment: As Henk pointed out, care must be taken if `generate_email` is also reading from stdin.

Comment: To read from an input stream without turning the `while` loop into a subshell (which would cause any variable values set inside the loop to be lost when it exits), use process substitution instead of a pipe. `while read -r ... done < <(grep ...)`

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it's not hanging, but just waiting for input.

Watch out though and make sure that `generate_email` does not read from the same input stream.